# Visual Studio Code Git Branches

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-commit

I am new to VSC and coding in general. I am currently working in Visual Studio Code to create new data on our website. However I noticed that at the end of the day, I close my computer and then reopen it the next day and continue working on the same branch. Is this normal to do? Or should I always commit my work at the end of the day? What are the disadvantages of not committing at the end of the day?

Comment: if your hard disk crashes you have lost your work (if the git remote is on a different drive/computer). There is no difference if you commit local and not push to the remote

Comment: Your question suggests that you don't understand what Git is. I've written a tutorial that might help: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/